# How to successfully pin files to VSCode in Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, yaml, taskbar

I've got some configuration files (yml) which gets opened quite often.
These files should be easily accessible by pinning them on the Visual Studio Code icon on the Windows 10 task bar.
Unfortunately when I do so they are pinned, but when I want to open them I get a message like:

> The selected item is not available. It may have been moved, renamed, or removed.

What I could figure out is that files with the type "sql" in example works and "txt"-files can't even be pinned.
So I guess there is a sort of restriction for yml-Files.
Is there a workaround for that or do I miss something?

Pinning them as a tab in the editor is no option for me, cause it would be to messy.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  If you hover your mouse over the pinned item, is the file path in the tooltip what you expect?

Comment: It's the same path. I've added a screenshot in the description.
What's interesting is that the sql-file has an icon where it's pinned, but not the yml file. I don't know if that has a meaning, but I wonder why it's like that.

Comment: I think the icon is different because it can't find the file on disk (or at least, its failing to find it for some reason). That is a typical icon that will appear when Windows can no longer find said file anymore, or if something was uninstalled etc.  `tmp` indicates to me that that is some sort of temporary folder. Is this just a folder you have sitting in C:\?  Is some other process doing "things" with this directory?

Comment: Ah okay. Both files which got pinned are in the same directory (C:\tmp). The files are both empty. When I pin a yml-file it's from the start on not accessible. If I change the type to sql and pin it again the file is accessible. There is no process which uses this directory. MD- and json-files works too for example.

Comment: I can open these yml-files too. Just not opening them from the pin-section. Weird..

Comment: At this point, I'm unsure if this is really a Visual Studio Code problem.  I guess an easy thing to try is update VS Code if its not the latest version already.  Otherwise, probably best to go to their github and log an issue for further help. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with your file associations in your Windows settings. When you install VS Code, IIRC, there is some kind of option to create some default file associations for certain file extensions to open with VS Code. The behaviour you're observing with .sql and .yml files is probably a result of that. Try modifying your Windows settings to associate the .yml extension to VS Code. see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs-in-windows-e5d82cad-17d1-c53b-3505-f10a32e1894d and https://superuser.com/q/29717/1749748. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I installed the latest version, but there was no change in the behaviour.

Comment: The file association was already done by me and the configuration options the people suggested from your sites were set correct too. I guess I have to create an issue in github. But thanks for your support!